# Увеличение картинки по клику

Tags: jquery, php, html

Как сделать увеличение картинки при клике? (Поверх всех картинок в форме цветом "firebrick" ). Искал в гугле, но ничего оптимального не нашел.  Увеличиться должна картинка с кодом.

```
<img  class='avatar' alt='аватар'  src='$myrow[avatar]'/><br>
```

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Почему бы не вспомнить о jQuery методе - animate ?

Comment: Я  просто плохо знаю всё это.